# What does Eastern-Orthodoxy teach about the Law and Gospel division?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, law-and-gospel

In Lutheranism, there is the concept that the whole of Scripture is divided into [Law and Gospel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_and_Gospel). The Law shows us our sins and how we ought to live. In essence, all that is required or that condemns us is law (including verses like "love your God with all your [...]" [Luke 10:27](http://biblehub.com/luke/10-27.htm)).

The Gospel is God's grace and mercy bestowed on us (including verses like "Behold, the Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world!" [John 1:29](http://biblehub.com/luke/10-27.htm)).

What does the Orthodox Church teach about this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only liturgical text that would come close to such a distinction would be the [hymn to the Holy Archangels Michael and Gabriel](http://www.doxologia.ro/ceaslov/acatiste/acatistul-sfintilor-arhangheli-mihail-gavriil), available on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTmNO8a47VU):

> Let us all who cherish feasts praise the leaders of the angels of the Trinity, Michael and Gabriel, by taking cover under their wings, so that we may be delivered from all sorts of troubles, to one saying: rejoice, *servant of the law*, and to the other singing: rejoice, *angel of grace!*

The above is the first of two dozen short stanzas, dedicated to the abovementioned angels, half of which end in *rejoice, servant of the law*, and the other half in *rejoice, angel of grace!* As our Latin forefathers so aptly put it, [lex orandi, lex credendi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_orandi,_lex_credendi).

Comment: more than enough, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The Eastern Orthodox being Christians also believes in the teaching of saint Paul on the subject, but they have a different theology than Lutheranism.    Probably the Best way to answer your question (without spending tons of time researching it) is to point you to an article that covers the correspondence made between Lutheran theologians and an Eastern Orthodox Patriarch that took place a few decades after the death of Martin Luther.

Justification by Faith Alone?
The Reply of Patriarch Jeremiah II to the Lutheran Tübingen Theologians, Concerning the Augsburg Confession (16th cent.)

"... The same also do the ancient writers of the Church teach; for Ambrose saith: 'This is ordained of God, that he that believeth in Christ shall be saved, without works, by faith alone, freely receiving remission of sins." —Article VI of the Augsburg Confession

http://orthodoxinfo.com/inquirers/faithalone.aspx

Here is another article that covers the basic areas of Agreement and disagreement between Lutherans and the Eastern Orthodox in regards to that early contact by the Tubingen theologians.

http://web.archive.org/web/20130128052302/http://www.stpaulsirvine.org/html/sixteenthcentury.htm